# Set bool to false if string is null

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I am looking for a way to set a bool value to false if a string value is null. I could easily do this using an if statement, but was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

I would need something that does the same thing as this if statement:

```
if (stringValue != null)
   boolValue = true;
else
   boolValue = false;
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry for the dumb question, my brain isn't working today.

Comment: what's with all the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the variable directly equal to the condition in your if statement.

```
boolValue = (stringValue != null)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
boolValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue);
```

EDIT:

If you really just want to check if the string is `null` and not `NullOrEmpty` (there is a difference) then use

```
boolValue = stringValue != null;
```

Comment: Technically this doesn't accomplish the same thing as that which is posted. Bill's does.

Comment: Correct this will set the boolvalue even if the string is just empty but not null

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't accomplish it all, because you'll need to use 2 lines, but, you could first use the string.Trim() method to remove all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.After you declare that the bool value equals the result of string.IsNullOrEmpty().

```
stringvalue.Trim();
boolValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue);
```

Or, you could also:

```
boolValue = (stringvalue != null);
```

Comment: Why are you including `string.Trim()`? OP is asking about null, not empty or whitespace.

Comment: Just to check if the String doesn't consist on something like "          ". 
An interesting consistency test for this type of case.But it isn't truly necessary.

Comment: That is commonly a useful check, but I think it is misleading in this case. Depending on the circumstance, empty strings can be okay but null not.

Comment: Fair, not knowing which is the specific case of use makes it hard to answer, I just included it because I thought it might be checking the string for using in a Sql string or something like that.

Comment: If the string is null, then `Trim` would throw a null reference exception and you'd never get to the `IsNullOrEmpty` test. A better way to do what you're trying to show would be `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`... But again the OP explicitly asks for null only